# How can I test my application's network footprint?

Tags: .net, networking, bandwidth, throughput

I have no experience in network administration, so apologies if this is a clumsy question.

I have a .NET application to deploy locally at my client's site.  They have the hardware to do this, but have concerns about the network capability.

Infrastructure

- My client has a 2mb upload/download network connection.
- They currently serve webmail to 260 users.

Web app

- The web application will be used by ~200 users
- Each user will probably log in a couple of times a week, no spike time of day.
- An average usage would probably involve the download/upload of about 5 fairly small form pages (5-15 fields)

My gut feel is that this is very low usage, and shouldn't cause much impact on their current setup.  However, I would like to verify this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate typical workload and run sniffer like `tcpdump`, writing raw packets to dump file. At the end of the day you can examine dump's contents to see how much of bandwidth your application utilized.
Sample command-line:

```
tcpdump -w dump.log port PORT_OF_YOUR_APPLICATION_HERE
```

There are few ports of tcpdump to windows platform.

Comment: Thanks very much, I may have a further question when I get the data though!